# SQL Server Management Studio connection fails to COM errors

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I have an instance of SQL Server 2008 running on a Windows 2008 server. I am able to connect to this SQL server from several machines on my network. However, I **cannot** connect using SQL Management Studio on the SQL Server itself.

When I hit "Connect" I get this error:

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). (Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop)

Server config:

- SQL Server 2005
- Windows Server 2008 Std 32-bit
- Also runs SQL Server 2000 on port 1444

I tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling SQL Management Studio
- Adding these [registry entries](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqltools/thread/d5d3e5fc-d8ce-4f42-b7ea-9bbbb7756a20)
- Rebooting
- Running these [commands](http://msmvps.com/blogs/martinpoon/archive/2009/03/20/ssms-unable-to-cast-com-object-of-type-system-comobject-to-interface-type-microsoft-visualstudio-ole-interop-iserviceprovider-exception-from-hresult-0x80004002-e-nointerface.aspx):

> for %1 in (%windir%\system32*.dll) do regsvr32 /s %1
>
> for %1 in (%windir%\system32*.ocx) do regsvr32 /s %1

- Running regsvr32 actxprxy.dll, which produced an error

Any ideas?

Justin

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed too?  Which version, I have seen this product cause problems with SQL Server 2008 Management Tools IF it was installed AFTER installing SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @JD - Thanks. I have SQL Server 2005 installed, not 2008. And I do have VS 2005 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unregister actxprxy.dll then reregister it

run

```
regsvr32.exe –r c:\windows\system32\actxprxy.dll
regsvr32.exe c:\windows\system32\actxprxy.dll
```

run these in a command prompt as administrator

On Windows2008 server, the command for unregister is:

```
 regsvr32.exe /u c:\windows\system32\actxprxy.dll
```

Comment: No. SQL Server Management Studio 9 (which is 2005)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to do a repair on your SSMS on your server (if I'm understanding you correctly).  I appears that the COM Interfaces need repaired/reinstalled.

-JFV

Comment: Modify the install from add/remove and remove.  Then install workstation components if you don't see repair.

Comment: I tried a repair on Native Client and 2005 itself. Neither worked.

Comment: OK, that didn't work. Any other ideas?